# PowerShell Имя пользователя который выполнил сценарий

Tags: powershell

Как получить имя пользователя который запустил скрипт PowerShell?

Comment: [Оно?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2085755/5045688)

Comment: нет. который запустил != который залогинился в систему

Comment: Извлеките имя запустившего процесс из токена последнего.

Answer (score 0):

В **Powershell** можно получить имя пользователя через команду:

```ps
whoami
```

Это будет именем пользователя через которого запустилась команда, это же доказывает эксплойт ***CVE-2017-0213*** для получения системных привилегий/прав у обычного пользователя.